# Настройка DNS Bind9

Tags: dns, bind9

Добрый день, дорогие друзья. Есть вопрос по *Bind9*. Я в нём только начинаю разбираться и вот появилась задача где нужно перенаправлять все запросы на DNS на 1 IP. То есть на любой запрос домена, DNS сервер должен ответить одним  IP-адресом.

Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Идём в файл `/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones`. Находим запись о корневой зоне. Она имеет следующий вид:

```
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
}
```

Меняем её на следующую:

```
zone "." {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.fakeroot";
}
```

Далее создаём файл `/etc/bind/db.fakeroot` со следующим содержимым:

```
; Стартовая запись зоны.
@ IN SOA ns.example.com. admin.example.com ( ; Основной сервер имён, e-mail администратора.
    2016061001 ; Серийный номер.
    1h         ; Интервал обновления для вторичных серверов.
    1h         ; Интервал повтора запроса вторичного сервера при неудаче.
    1w         ; Время обслуживания зоны вторичными серверами при отказе первичного.
    1h         ; Время кэширования отрицательных ответов.
)

  IN NS   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
* IN A    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

(Подставляем здесь вместо `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` требуемый адрес.)

Далее перезапускаем сервер командой `rndc reload` и радуемся результату.

Если хотим перенаправлять на свой сервер также и *IPv6*-трафик, то добавляем в `/etc/bind/db.fakeroot` строку следующего вида:

```
* IN AAAA xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
```

(Подставляем здесь вместо `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx` требуемый *IPv6*-адрес.)